# Loading data asynchronously with Javascript and ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, asynchronous

I found this JS snippet for loading data asynchronously with Javascript:

```
(function(){
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.async = true;
    a.src = 'http://www.example.com/somefile.js';
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
})();
```

The idea was that a user would put this code into his HTML and then from my Ruby On Rails would be loaded images and displayed on his website.

But how to load data with the JS snippet from my Rails app?

Comment: search AJAX in google

Comment: But for example, `http://www.example.com/somefile.js` how can I add some parameters into the call?

Answer (score -1):

Load following file instead of your js, run your php on somefile.php file and throw out a javascript call to your js function to display the image

```
a.src = 'http://www.example.com/somefile.php';
```

Comment: Question is about ruby on rails, not php.